# Using ENS as address inside a contract

Tags: solidity, addresses, ens

Is it possible to use a ENS name as an address in solidity, instead of having to use the usual long address?

Example:

```
address public _address = myname.eth;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It is... but it isn't...

You can't do it like you present above, but you ***could*** call the ENS contract to get the resolver contract address, then call the resolver contract to get the name's contract address...

This would cost a bit of gas though, so you're probably best just looking up the address and entering it in directly; unless of course you need it to be continuously up to date with the current live address.